# JavaScript Navigation Div Spy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm attempting to recreate the bootstrap scrollspy feature but unfortunately it's not going to well. I can get to the point to which it can get the div and highlight the navigation link, but I cannot remove the highlighting when I scroll past the div. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have a JSFiddle if you wish to see it (ignore the styling and the main page content, it's just dummy text).

http://jsfiddle.net/J7sxD/3/

```
var scrollArea = $(window).scrollTop()+45;
$('div[id^="section"]').each(function() {
  elTop = $(this).offset().top;
  elBtm = elTop + $(this).height();
  if (elTop < scrollArea && elBtm > scrollArea) {
    var name = $(this).attr('id').substring(8);
            $('a#'+name).addClass("active");
            $('a#'+name).addClass("current");
            $('a[class^="current"]').each(function() {
                if($(this).attr('id').substring(8) != name){
                    $(this).removeClass("current");
                }
            });
  } else {
    $('a[class^="active"]').each(function() {
                if(!$(this).hasClass("current")){
                    $(this).removeClass("active");
                }
            });
  }
});
```

Comment: Maybe due to the reason that I wish to create it myself?

Comment: no need to be rude. have a look at their javascript, and good luck to you. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/scrollspy.js